How to get built-in method's type annotations as a string?
I'd wrote a function, that takes any python object and create file.py: a synopsis about the object with listing and describing all of it's methods.
For example, when I pass 'str' to function, I get <class 'str'> synopsis.py, which includes such info block as:
"""
upper()
Return a copy of the string converted to uppercase.
"""
...

The 'upper' string is taken from dir(str).
The describing string is taken from getattr(str, 'upper').__doc__
But I can't get THIS string yet: "def upper(self: LiteralString) -> LiteralString" (or, maybe, string like this).
Its appear in PyCharm Documentation Popup when You hover over the str.upper() method.
I had try to get access to source file for such methods (builtins.py) to get this annotation string somehow, but failed in it.

Potential duplicate: Where can I find the type annotations for methods of built-in types like set.symmetric_difference?. Basically, you will have to parse typeshed yourself.

For normal symbols: How to get class variables and type hints?, How to access Type Hints inside of a method after it's called in Python.

I may be misunderstanding, but it sounds like you'll want to use the built-in inspect module. It can provide information about objects and even print out their source code (provided it's saved in a file). I recommend taking a look at the documentation as it's fairly substantial.
Here's a basic example where I've defined a function and a class and used inspect to get info about each:
import inspect


def simple_func(name: str) -> None:
    """Say hello to `name`"""
    print(f'Hello {name}')


class SimpleClass:
    """Class Level Docstring"""
    def __init__(self, name: str) -> None:
        """Method docstring for __init__"""
        self.name = name

    def simple_method(self) -> None:
        """Say hello to `name`"""
        print(f'Hello {self.name}')


print(inspect.getmembers(SimpleClass))  # get info on all memebers of 'simple_class'

print(inspect.getsource(simple_func))  # prints the source code of 'simple_func'

print(inspect.getsource(SimpleClass))  # prints the source code of 'simple_class'


I'd tried this module - it can't return such string and it often don't work with builtins at all.
